Custom tag helper automatically removes attributes from markup
Consider a custom tag helper with this:
[HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = "custom")]
public class CustomTagHelper : TagHelper
{

  [HtmlAttributeName("foo")]
  public string? Foo { get; set; }

  // ...

And this razor markup:
<a custom foo="bar" ... 

The rendered markup:
<a ... 

The foo attribute is missing in the rendered markup. If I remove the Foo property, it remains. So the tag helper removes such public properties.
I can't find anything in the docs that describe this behaviour, so I don't know whether it's normal or the problem lies elsewhere.
Is this expected behaviour? If so, why does it work this way?
(My workaround is to re-add that attribute manually.)

In ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers, when you define a property with an HtmlAttributeName, the attribute is processed and consumed by the Tag Helper and does not automatically appear in the rendered HTML unless explicitly re-added. This behavior allows for custom handling of attributes within the Tag Helper. In that case, you need to explicitly add them back in the Process method of your Tag Helper using output.Attributes.SetAttribute("foo", Foo)

@MdFaridUddinKiron Yes I'm re-adding the attribute. Surprising behaviour, more so because it's not documented anywhere.
